# In-app Billing V3 getSkuDetails() returns empty DETAILS_LIST

Tags: android, android-billing

I've noticed `getSkuDetails()` intermittently returns an empty or partial `DETAILS_LIST` with `RESPONSE_CODE=0`. My application is published in Draft mode, and my Gmail address is on the list of accounts with testing access. After a day or so the problem seems to resolve without any action.

- Could my application be misconfigured in the Developer Console?
- Have others observed this in unpublished applications or have another explanation?

Answer (score 1):

In in-app Billing V3, *getSkuDetails()* caches the result locally. So, during the next call it shows the cached result *(performance improvement)*. It resets the cache after 24 hrs or so. This is the reason why you got everything working, the next day.

You need not to worry about this.